# to return unique indices of equal elements in two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays; one is bigger than the other. I want my function to return the indices of the common elements concerning the bigger one, and this returned list of indices should have unique values, for example :

```
search = np.array([1,3,4,5,8,10,7,3,4,5,8,7])

data = np.array([7,10,1,12,7,1,5,18,4,3,10,5,8,4])
```

## my function output should look like :

```
result = [2,9,none,6,12,10,0,9,13,11,none,4]
```

So, the first element in **results** is 2, which means that the first element in **search** can be found at the third element of **data**

*However*, we have two elements with value 4 in **search**, and one element with 4 value in **data**, so the first 4 value (9th element of search) will be mapped to 13, and the other 4 value should be assigned to another index if available, if there isn't another value, zero or none should be assigned to its index

I found this code in a previous question, this code will do this job, but the resulted array of indices have duplicates :

```
x = np.array([3, 5, 7, 1, 9, 8, 6])
y = np.array([2, 1, 5, 10, 100, 6,6])

index = np.argsort(x)
sorted_x = x[index]
sorted_index = np.searchsorted(sorted_x, y)

yindex = np.take(index, sorted_index, mode="clip")
mask = x[yindex] != y

result = np.ma.array(yindex, mask=mask)
print (result)

# result =[[-- 3 1 -- -- 6 6]]
```

For my case, there shouldn't be duplicated, instead of the second 6 value in result array, zero or none.

Comment: in your example 7,10,1,5 and 4 all look to be repeated in data

Comment: yes , in both search and data arrays ,there are duplicate

Comment: still confusing: there is one 1 in search but two 1s in data, two 2s in search but one 2 in data, two 4s in search and two 4s in data. So maybe that's the pattern that generates a none. However there are two 5s in search and two 5s in data and two 7s in search and two 7s in data. Your description of what should happen doesn't really explain why you assign the index 9 to both 3s in search.